What is the variance of one coordinate of a uniformly sampled point in a 10-dimensional ball?
I encountered the following question.

If $(X_1, X_2,..., X_{10})$ is a point uniformly sampled from a $10$-dimensional ball with radius $12$ centered at the origin, find the variance of $X_1$, the first coordinate.

I attempted to solve this question as follows. Let $V_k(x)$ denote the volume of a $k$-dimensional ball with radius $x$ (volume formula). Then,
$$Var(X_1) = \frac{1}{V_{10}(12)}\int_{-r}^r{x^2}V_{9}(|x|) dx \\  
 = \frac{2}{V_{10}(12)}\int_{0}^r{x^2}V_{9}(x) dx \\
= \frac{2 \times 120 \times 32 \times \pi^4}{\pi^5 \times 12^{10}\times 945}\int_{0}^r{x^{11}} dx \\ 
= \frac{2 \times 120 \times 32 \times \pi^4 \times 12^{12}}{\pi^5 \times 12^{10}\times 945\times 12} = \frac{2048}{21\pi}.$$
However, the answer given as correct is 12. Where is the flow in my logic? Thanks in advance.
PS: To clarify, I am more interested in finding my mistake rather than being provided with a solution to the question.

Your solution can be corrected as follows:
$$\text{Var}(X_1)=\\\int_{x_1^2+\dots+x^2_{10}\le r^2} \frac{x^2_1}{V_{10}(r)}\text{d}x_1\dots \text{d}x_{10}=\\ \frac{1}{V_{10}(12)}\int_{-r}^r{x^2}V_{9}\left (\color{blue}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}} \right) \text{d}x= \\ \frac{2 \times 120\times 32 \times \pi^4}{\pi^5 \times 12^{10}\times945}\int_{0}^r{x^{2}(r^2-x^2)^{\frac{9}{2}}}\text{d}x= \\ \frac{2 \times 120\times 32 \times \pi^4}{\pi^5 \times 12^{10}\times 945} 12^{12} \int_{0}^1{x^{2}(1-x^2)^{\frac{9}{2}}} \text{d}x =\\  
12 \times \frac{2048}{21\pi} \int_{0}^1{x^{2}(1-x^2)^{\frac{9}{2}}}\text{d}x=12$$
by noting that $\int_{0}^1{x^{2}(1-x^2)^{\frac{9}{2}}} \text{d}x=\frac{21\pi}{2048}$ (source).
